# Angular 2 checkbox validation

Tags: angular6, angular5, angular2-forms, angular7

I am trying to validate checkbox in angular 2 by template driven but not working.I have searched in google also no one answered properly.Any genius can answer this question?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9nkywb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

app.component.html

```
     <form #f="ngForm"> 
 <input type="checkbox" name="isTCAccepted" [ngModel]="user" required 
     #tc="ngModel">Name1
     <input type="checkbox" name="isTCAccepted" [ngModel]="user" required 
      #tc="ngModel">Name2
     <input type="checkbox" name="isTCAccepted" [ngModel]="user" required 
     #tc="ngModel">Name3

     <div *ngIf="tc.invalid && f.submitted"> 
     Please check atleast one
     </div>  
     <button>Submit</button>
     </form>
```

Comment: Have a look at my library Easy Angular, makes form validation a breeze. It is production ready but sorry about the lack of docs so far, they are coming soon. https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ezng Here is a demo on stackbitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8brst8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Can you edit my stackblitz?

Comment: check this stackblitz: does it work for you? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1uzdf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

As I see, Everything is fine with the code except that name for the input tags should be different, you can have a look into below code,
`

```
<form #f="ngForm"> 
     <input type="checkbox" name="isTCAccepted1" [ngModel]="user" required 
     #tc1="ngModel">Name1
     <input type="checkbox" name="isTCAccepted2" [ngModel]="user" required 
      #tc2="ngModel">Name2
     <input type="checkbox" name="isTCAccepted3" [ngModel]="user" required 
     #tc3="ngModel">Name3
 <div *ngIf="(tc1.invalid && tc2.invalid && tc3.invalid) && f.submitted">
     Please check atleast one
 </div>
 <button>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

`

Comment: Can you please add explanation with relevant example?